# Arrays differ while using numpy hstack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have over 1200 images that I resize to be the same (256, 256) size:

```py
filenames = glob('data/*.png')
for filename in filenames:
    im = skimage.io.imread(filename)

    im = skimage.transform.resize(im, (256, 256), anti_aliasing=True)
        
    im = skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(im)
    skimage.io.imsave(filename, I'm)
```

And when I combine certain images via the following:

```py
filenames = sorted(glob('data/pic_f.*.png'))
k = 0
for filename in tqdm(filenames):
    images = [filename, filename.replace('_f', '_r')]
    images = [Image.open(image) for image in images]
    
    min_shape = sorted([(np.sum(image.size), image.size) for image in images])[0][1]
    imgs_comb = np.hstack((np.asarray(image.resize(min_shape)) for image in images))

    imgs_comb = Image.fromarray(imgs_comb)
    imgs_comb.save('data/mugshot_comp.{}.png'.format(k))
    k += 1
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ea68e88f7337> in <module> 
7 
8 min_shape = sorted([(np.sum(image.size), image.size) for image in images])[0][1] 
----> 9 imgs_comb = np.hstack((np.asarray(image.resize(min_shape)) for image in images)) 
10 
11 imgs_comb = Image.fromarray(imgs_comb)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup) 
286 return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0) 
287 else: 
--> 288 return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1) 
289 
290
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Anything I am missing here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's worth making sure that your input images aren't a mixture of colour and grayscale.

Comment: Adding skimage.color.rgb2gray fixed the issue. Thanks for the pointer @motto

Comment: Awesome. I've been down that hole before :-)

Comment: An easier solution is to read in images with the as_grey flag set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the as_grey flag fixed the issue:

```py
filenames = glob('data/*.png')
for filename in filenames:
    im = skimage.io.imread(filename, as_grey=True)

    im = skimage.transform.resize(im, (256, 256), anti_aliasing=True)
        
    im = skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(im)
    skimage.io.imsave(filename, I'm)
```